# How to retrieve a bitmap from a HasMap<String, object>

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

In my app i use `HashMap<String, Object>` to store data of string type and bitmap type. How can I retrieve the bitmap back from the HashMap and use for my ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: There is no code my friend.I just want to retrive a bitmap that is stored in a  hashmap and use it as a resourse of an image view.But the problem that I have is that is stored as an Object and I dont know if i can convert it back to bitmap or not.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, just cast.

```
    //Earlier
    HashMap<String,Object> mMap = ...;
    mMap.put("bitmap_key_001", someBitmpap);

    //Retrieve
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) mMap.get("bitmap_key_001");
```

Comment: Though not mentioned I would be wary of storing too many bitmaps in a map. You will run out of memory pretty quickly. Some kind of LRU cache is likely a better option.